# My .txt file reads into my notebook as one column as opposed to three separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files

I used the following code which worked, but I had to erase the headers in the original .txt file in order for this to work.

```
por_layer5 =  pd.read_csv("Sample_File.txt",comment='#', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to read in the .txt file and set conditions that only read in the integers and separate them into three columns without having to edit the original .txt file. I provided a preview of the first lines from the file that include the headers. My original thought was to index into the file to read-only when the numbers start (its index number is 4), but I've had trouble doing so.

[Sample of the first couple of lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qySY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `skiprows` option in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
pd.read_csv("Sample_File.txt",comment='#', header=None, skiprows=4,delim_whitespace=True)
```